# Starting ActiveMQ Artemis without credentials

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am new to ActiveMQ Artemis, and I want to start the broker without security by setting the `security-enabled` flag to `false`.
I did the change in config file, but when I do `artemis run` I get message that are in the screenshot. Is there a way to start broker without getting these messages or supplying user/password?
[image]

Comment: Please provide the contents of your `broker.xml`, `bootstrap.xml`, and `login.config`.

Comment: Also, please don't provide screenshots of error messages. Rather cut & paste the text into the question so it can be searched.

Comment: hi Yes, thank you  by putting the  tag <security-enabled> in correct place in the properties file.

Comment: What place exactly was the "correct place in the properties file"?